# Overlaying Elements with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm looking for a solution for a html screen. It contains two blocks, and the one below overlaps the one above a bit.

I know how to make rounded corners but not how to overlap the two div's.

[image: Overlapping components]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `position: relative; top: 5000px; z-index: 9988776554;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <image src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  <div class="content">text</div>
</div>
```