# How to overlay an image with text that has a background with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I need to replicate in HTML what you see in this image:

[image]

The issue is that the text is overlaying a div with a background image.  If there wasn't an image in the outer div and a solid colour, I can imagine that I'd be able to do this fairly easily with a few small html elements with rounded corners placed in the correct places, however the background image is what adds the complexity.

So far I have this... as you can see, two of the rounded corners I am stuck on.   Can anyone suggest a solution ?   Note that it must work in **all modern browsers**:

```css
#outer {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-image:url(https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1323032473/es/vector/panal-abstracto-de-vector-azul-moderno-con-fondo-de-monitor-de-coraz%C3%B3n-con-para-la.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=mXe4wSHc8kAcOXastbN9jhinrWGQX3vvJQUhDgvOcqA=);
    position:relative;
}
#innertext {
    display:inline;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:5px 25px 0px 5px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#000;
    
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="innertext">A test title<br>that is on two lines</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the image background doesn't really matter, if you just use a PNG with a transparent background.

Comment: You might want to check out [this recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khjVPkO35F0) by Kevin Powell.

Comment: [Here's something I've been thinking of.](https://jsfiddle.net/cw5uo083/) Not a perfect solution but something I've been thinking of.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68934484/overlaying-elements-with-rounded-corners  this is a bit similar might helps, Consider wrapping it in a flex column container, with each child div having the right :after, and only the first with the top :before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add `:before` and `:after` to the `.innertext` element

**UPDATE:**

to have multiple lines, just add a `flex-direction: column` container, and every line will have the `:after` (right) corner, and only the first child will have the `:before` (top) corner

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1323032473/es/vector/panal-abstracto-de-vector-azul-moderno-con-fondo-de-monitor-de-coraz%C3%B3n-con-para-la.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=mXe4wSHc8kAcOXastbN9jhinrWGQX3vvJQUhDgvOcqA=);
  position: relative;
}
#inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.innertext {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 25px 0px 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000;
}
.innertext:first-child::before,
.innertext::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 40px;    /* double the radius */
  height: 40px;   /* double the radius */
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 0 0 #fff;  /* this to create the inverted corner border radius area, if you desire to change the positon you can control it via the first two values 0 20px which represents the x & y */
}
.innertext::before {
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
}
.innertext::after {
  right: -40px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.innertext span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;   /* to overcome the overlapping with the text */
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner-container">
    <div class="innertext"><span>A test</span></div>
    <div class="innertext"><span>A test with a second line</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @biskrem that works very well but it's not quite what I need.  A part of the complexity is that the text is on two lines in my original reference image.    I can make the inner text inlinewraps the point where it wraps has no curved edge and it also doesn't wrap at the break tag.  I will slightly update my sample code to show this.

Comment: @AdamJones you can achieve the desired results by multiple divs in a flex column container, which each child div has the right `:after`, and only the first with the top `:before`

Comment: You could use `box-shadow: -7px 5px 0 0 #fff;` to avoid overlapping the text and then not need `span`

Comment: This is the closest to getting it working in all browsers.  I had to use an inline svg ultimately to get it to work and doing it inline means that it also works on Safari.  You can see the final results at https://viridianapartments.com/

Answer (score 2):

I will reuse the same idea I used in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62341241/8620333) where I considered and SVG filter to create the rounded corners.

```css
#outer {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1323032473/es/vector/panal-abstracto-de-vector-azul-moderno-con-fondo-de-monitor-de-coraz%C3%B3n-con-para-la.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=mXe4wSHc8kAcOXastbN9jhinrWGQX3vvJQUhDgvOcqA=);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* place the div at the bottom left */
#innertext {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  filter: url('#round'); /* apply the filter to round the corners*/
}
/* use an inline element inside */
#innertext > span {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /* make sure the padding apply to all the lines */
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
          box-decoration-break: clone;
}
/* add two lines on the left and the bottom to complete the puzzle */
#innertext:before,
#innertext:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #fff;
  left:-10px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
/* vertical line */
#innertext:before {
  height: 999px; /* very big value */
  width: 20px;
}
/* horizontal line */
#innertext:after {
  width: 999px; /* very big value */
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="innertext"><span>A test title<br>that is on two lines</span></div>
</div>

<!-- the SVG filter -->
<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <filter id="round">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -8" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Here is the code without the filter to understand the structure:

```css
#outer {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1323032473/es/vector/panal-abstracto-de-vector-azul-moderno-con-fondo-de-monitor-de-coraz%C3%B3n-con-para-la.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=mXe4wSHc8kAcOXastbN9jhinrWGQX3vvJQUhDgvOcqA=);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* place the div at the bottom left */
#innertext {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
/* use an inline element inside */
#innertext > span {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /* make sure the padding apply to all the lines */
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
          box-decoration-break: clone;
}
/* add two lines on the left and the bottom to complete the puzzle */
#innertext:before,
#innertext:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left:-10px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
/* vertical line */
#innertext:before {
  height: 999px; /* very big value */
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}
/* horizontal line */
#innertext:after {
  width: 999px; /* very big value */
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="innertext"><span>A test title<br>that is on two lines</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great however it's not super flexible if I need to modify the page more in some ways.  For example, if I want to add curved corners to all corners of my outer div (with the image), this solution suddenly doesn't work.  Is there a way around that ?

Comment: @AdamJones *if I want to add curved corners to all corners* --> that was not part of the question so I didn't consider it. My solution cover the requirements you shared. If you want something different, you will need a different solution

Comment: Ok fair comment.... one other thing, does this work for you on iOS?   It doesn't seem to for me.

Comment: As I was reading the question, I thought "If this is possible, Temani Afif would be the one with the know-how, possibly using clip-path." :D With this solution, I can make out the corners (more or less apparent depending on the angle at which I'm looking at the screen), which become even more apparent when the text is user-selected. In Firefox, the last word "lines" gets wrapped to a third line.

Answer (score 2):

This adds a few pseudo elements to the text that create the shapes around the text. I had to modify the HTML a bit to accommodate these pseudo elements; was not sure if that was okay. Try this out and see if it works in all your required browsers.

```css
:root {
  --border-radius-size: 20px;
}
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
  background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1323032473/es/vector/panal-abstracto-de-vector-azul-moderno-con-fondo-de-monitor-de-coraz%C3%B3n-con-para-la.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=mXe4wSHc8kAcOXastbN9jhinrWGQX3vvJQUhDgvOcqA=);
  position: relative;
}
#innertext {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#innertext > div {
  position: relative;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 25px 0 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
}
#innertext > div::before,
#innertext > div::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: var(--border-radius-size);
  height: calc(var(--border-radius-size) * 2);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: var(--border-radius-size);
  box-shadow: #fff 0 calc(-1 * var(--border-radius-size)) 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top;
}
#innertext > div::before {
  inset: 
    calc(var(--border-radius-size) * -0.5) 
    auto 
    auto 
    calc(var(--border-radius-size) * -0.5);
}
#innertext > div::after {
  inset: 
    auto 
    calc(var(--border-radius-size) * -0.5) 
    calc(var(--border-radius-size) * -1.5) 
    auto;
}
/* Note: You will probably want to make sure that these corner effects do not happen on very small screens - maybe instead make the text full width instead. */
```

```html
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76416933/how-to-overlay-an-image-with-text-that-has-a-background-with-rounded-corners -->
<div id="outer">
    <div id="innertext">
      <div>A test title</div>
      <div>that is on two lines</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).